# In TypeScript, is it possible to pass in a string to a generic and then use it as a key of the type/interface?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

This is basically what I was hoping to accomplish but it is no go for launch:

```js
type MyType<
  T extends {},
  K extends string = 'keyName'
> = T & {
  [K]: {
    value: string
  }
};
```

> A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression
> whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.ts

Is there any way to pass in a key and have it shape the resulting `type` or `interface`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `[key in K]`.

```
type MyType<
  T extends {},
  K extends string = "keyName"
  > = T & {
    [key in K]: {
      value: string
    }
  };
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=8&ssc=5&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq4IB4CwAoKV5QgD2AgDsATAZygG8BfAGgywGlcDjyozgAnASyIHMoAXigAiANYQQAOQCGAWwiiGUAHzDsUAGRUVWANqSQUPlEYBdAFy7MWOwDdZAGwCuEa514C9UaiuoA3EA)

Comment: Thanks :). I was unaware of `key in`.